# In resticted domain , Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, convexity-inequality

I see this problem a few days ago.

$$ a, b, c  \in [\alpha , \beta]  $$
prove that $$ 9 \le  (a+b+c)\biggl( \frac {1}{a} + \frac{1} {b} + \frac{1} {c} \biggr)\le \frac{(2 \alpha + \beta )(\alpha + 2\beta )}{ \alpha \beta}$$

Left inequality is easy by Cauchy-Schwart's inequality. But Right inequality is difficult to me. How can I approach the Right inequlity?

EDIT : Sorry, I forgot the condition :  $  \alpha , \beta >0 $

Comment: The name is [Hermann Amandus Schwar**z**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Schwarz)

Comment: @MartinR/ Thanks. I edit the spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you mean that $\alpha>0$.

Let $f(a,b,c)=(a+b+c)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\right)$.

Thus, $f$ is a convex function of $a$, of $b$ and of $c$ (for example, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a^2}=\frac{2(b+c)}{a^3}>0$), which says that 
$$\max_{\{a,b,c\}\subset[\alpha,\beta]}f=\max_{\{a,b,c\}\subset\{\alpha,\beta\}}f=f(\alpha,\alpha,\beta)=\frac{(2\alpha+\beta)(\alpha+2\beta)}{\alpha\beta}$$ because $f(\alpha,\alpha,\alpha)=f(\beta,\beta,\beta)=9$ and by AM-GM
$$\frac{(2\alpha+\beta)(\alpha+2\beta)}{\alpha\beta}=2\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)+5\geq4+5=9.$$

Comment: Thanks ,, But one more question,, If the function is convex then why $ max f = f(\alpha, \alpha , \beta) ?$

Comment: Draw the graph of convex function $f$ on $[\alpha,\beta]$. Now, you can see that $\max\limits_{[\alpha,\beta]}f=\max\{f(\alpha),f(\beta)\}$.

Comment: Oh,, I understand your meaning..thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!